# Counting number of items in nested array ExpressJS

Tags: arrays, express, sequelize.js

Inserting items into database using Sequelize in ExpressJS. Depending on the number of items being inserted from the view either create or bulkcreate is used.

```
module.exports.create = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const plan_id = req.body.plan_id;
    if(req.body.activities < 2) {
      let activities = {
        activity_name: req.body.activities[0].name,
        comment: req.body.activities[0].comment,
        plans_id: plan_id
      }
      console.log(activities);
      await ActivityModel.Activity.create(activities);
      console.log('insert succeeded');
      res.redirect('/plans/edit/' + plan_id);
    }
    let activities = req.body.activities[0].name.map(
      (name, i) => {
        return {
          activity_name: name,
          comment: req.body.activities[0].comment[i],
          plans_id: plan_id
        }
      });
    await ActivityModel.Activity.bulkCreate(activities);

    res.redirect('/plans/edit/' + plan_id);
  }
  catch(error) {
    res.send(error);
  }
};
```

Tryting to use bulkcreate depending on the size of the activities[][name] array from the view template.

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="activities[][name]" placeholder="Activity">
  <label>Comment</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="activities[][comment]" placeholder="Comment">
```

When using activities[0].name.length, if there is only 1 item added the at a time req.body.activities looks like : `[ { name: 'asd', comment: 'asd' } ]` where name is an object. If more items are at a time `[ { name: [ 'a3', 'a4' ], comment: [ 'c3', 'c4' ] } ]` the name property becomes an array.

Looking for a way to measure this in the if statement in the controller to be able to bulkcreate many and if only 1 item, create a single instance.

Comment: can you post the sample array ,you are trying to access?

Comment: This is the output in the console `{ activity_name: [ 'test', 'test2' ],
  comment: [ 'test', 'test2' ],
  plans_id: '97' }`

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding a hidden input to the form with an array containing an index that increments for every instance added.

```
<input type="hidden" name="idx[]" value="0">
```

In the controller a chekc is run deciding if create or bulkcreate should be used.

```
if(req.body.idx <= 1)
```